# Sonarjava poor performance

Tags: java, performance, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We're using Sonarqube(6.3) to analyze the code on every build on our CI server.
Today I updated the Sonarjava version to 4.7.0.x after that on one of our projects we have a very poor performance analyzing with sonar-scanner.

Before the update the build took about a Minute. Now it takes 376 Minutes!

In the logfile I see a lot of these lines:
[INFO] 29/113 files analyzed, current file: /var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/131073/AIMRP-AIMRP38-STEP3/src/main/java/net/naomi/.../impl/ExcelExportController.java

Does somebody know what can be wrong here?
And, BTW, how can I open up a Issue ond the sonatype JIRA? There's no Create Button :D

thanks
Carsten

Comment: Best way to handle those kind of issue is through google groups : sonarqube@googlegroups.com 

I am currently working on this very topic through : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2214 and https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2215 

If you can share your problem on google groups and share your file, that would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: oh, and you don't want to go to sonatype jira but sonarsource, and while content is public, we keep opening of issues private to regroup requests.

Comment: Hi benzonico, thanks for your help. I have sent my problem at googlegroups. I have pasted the contents of my class.